# form validation on codeigniter if the value is empty and below 100

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

How to validate my form on codeigniter, if the value is empty and below 100.

**this is my controller**

```
function aksi_deposit(){
    if ((empty($_POST['deposit']))&& (($_POST['deposit'])<100)) {
        redirect('deposit');
    } else {
        $whc = $this->input->post('deposit');
        $money = $whc * 8000;
        $idUser= 1;
        $b['data'] = $this->m_user->tampil_invoice($idUser);
        $b['coin'] = $money;
        $b['whc'] = $whc;
        $this->load->view('user/v_invoice',$b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely if something if empty, it is below 100, do you mean empty OR below 100.

Comment: yes it is. Using "OR" this work 100%. thanks. And the code is:
if ((empty($_POST['deposit']))OR (($_POST['deposit'])<100)) {

Comment: honest question.. if you're using codeigniter, why not take advantage of CI's built-in form validation methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the solution, using "OR" it works 100 %.

```
if ((empty($_POST['deposit']))OR (($_POST['deposit'])<100)) {
        redirect('deposit');
    } else {
        $whc = $this->input->post('deposit');
        $money = $whc * 8000;
        $idUser= 1;
        $b['data'] = $this->m_user->tampil_invoice($idUser);
        $b['coin'] = $money;
        $b['whc'] = $whc;
        $this->load->view('user/v_invoice',$b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter you should benefit from its built-in form validation library it will handle everything perfectly for you and it is extremely easy to use, you will just load it like this:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$config = array(
    'field'     => 'deposite',
    'label'     => 'deposite',
    'rules' => array('trim','required', array('input_less_than_100',
        function($input)
        {
            return ( $input < 100 ) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }),
    ),
    'errors' => array(
        'input_less_than_100' => 'The %s field is less than 100.',
    ),
);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

Then run your validation like this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
{
    // do your magic
}
else
{
    // redirect if you want and then show form validation errors
}
```

You can use then validation errors like this:

```
$this->form_validation->error_array();
```